# Filtering the xml data is not working

Tags: php, xml

I use external xml, this works, but I have another problem. In my __construct I have $elem which is responsible for filtering the xml data. But it not working. Please help. I dont how to bite it.

```
class  Property {
    public $xmlClass;
    public $array = [];
    public $elem = '';
    public function __construct($xml,$elem) {
    $this->xmlClass=$xml;

      foreach($xml->list->film->$elem as $result) {
        $array = array_push($result);

      }
   }
}




$result_scenario = new Property($xml,'scenario');
print_r($result_scenario);
```

Comment: Instead of saying "It is not working" you should put information about what is happening. For example, are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 3):

The `array_push` method does not work like that.

You need to pass the array as the first parameter, than pass the element you want to push on it. In your case, it would be `array_push($this->array, $result);`. The function returns the new number of elements in the array.

See the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php